# how can i retrieve selected check_box_tag value from all pages ? actually in the controller i get only from one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatable

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => 'publishers', :action => 'playlist' ) do  %>
<table id='audio_list' >

  <thead>
     <tr>
      <th></th> 
       <th>Nr </th>
       <th>Title</th>

       <th></th>    
      </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>

<% @publishers.each do |publisher| %>
<tr>
   Here is my check_box_tag am sending to the controller
    <td><%= check_box_tag  "publisher_ids[]", publisher.id  %></td>
      <td><%=  publisher.id  %></td>
    <td><%=  publisher.title  %></td>  
    <%= link_to 'Play',  publisher ,:remote => true  %>  
    </td>      

 </tr> 
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>    
<br/>
<br/>
<%= submit_tag "Create Playlist" %>
<% end %>
```

controller is

```
def playlist
@test_list=Publisher.order('id DESC').find(params[:publisher_ids])
end
```

Now the controller gets checked value from only one page, i want to get checked value from all pages.

Comment: I can get value as array on the first page , when i click next page .. only the last page check_box value is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` returns one item, and its input, if trivial, is interpreted as that model's ID. Try `.find_all_by_publisher_id()`